# VBA Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error” after quarter of loop is done

Tags: vba, excel

hi I'm new to VBA and i have this weird error that accures quater through a loop which does nearly the same ever time.

```
Sub tabele_to_database()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Countries As New Collection
Dim things As New Collection
Dim Row As Boolean
Dim Coloum As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim a As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))

Row = True
Coloum = True
i = 2
While Row

    Countries.Add Sheets("payment terms").Cells(1, i).Value

    i = i + 1
    If IsEmpty(Sheets("payment terms").Cells(1, i)) Then
        Row = False
    End If
Wend

i = 2
While Coloum

    things.Add CStr(Sheets("payment terms").Cells(i, 1).Value)
    i = i + 1
    If IsEmpty(Sheets("payment terms").Cells(i, 1)) Then
        Coloum = False
    End If

Wend

a = 1

For Each thing In things

    For Each Country In Countries
        ws.Cells(1, a) = (thing + " " + Country)

        a = a + 1
    Next Country
Next thing



End Sub
```

The error is in

```
 ws.Cells(1, a) = (thing + " " + Country)
```

about quarter through the proccess.

the variables are a = 257 which is the amount of coloumns it printed
thing is the thing in the 7t row and country the country in the 36th so eveything should be fine

I know that thing and things aren't good names but I am at a internship and have no clue about most things.

It's for work but i am at a internship so i have no clue and I "learned" VBA just for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the values of the variables when the error occurs?  (Click `Debug` on the error and hover your mouse over each of the variables on the yellow highlighted line of code.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 ws.Cells(1, a) = (thing & " " & Country)
```

When concatenating set variables with a string, you need to use `&` instead of `+`

Edit: As pointed out by Vityata, this is a nice tip, but it doesn't fix the issue at hand.

Comment: You are absolutely right for the concatenation, but if this was the problem, the error would have been `13 - type mismatch`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint but that wasn't the issue

Comment: @Vityata Oh I see. Thanks for pointing that out - I'm still learning VBA aswell ;)

Comment: @DirtyDeffy - you are welcome. Actually the errors in VBA are quite helpful concerning the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
For Each thing In things
    For Each Country In Countries
        Debug.Print things + " " + Country
        ws.Cells(1, a) = thing + " " + Country
        a = a + 1
    Next Country
Next thing
```

Thus you would see what exactly causes the error. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to see the log.

The `+` is not a good concatenation sign, however, it may "work" if both `thing` and `Country` are numbers. The correct concatenation in VBA is with the `&`.

Another possible mistake is the usage of `Integer` - to be on the safe side with vba, use long.

Comment: The issue occures when it sets the value of the cell to "CIA XK"

Comment: @Gery120 - have you tried to change the `Long` to an `Integer`?

Comment: Yes but that wasn't the Problem..i figured it out i was using a old word version so here was a limit on colums

Answer (score 0):

On a old Excel version there is a limit for columns at about 250